# Definition of sparse graphs

Tags: networking, computer-science, bigdata, graph-theory

Im looking online for a good definition of sparse graphs, but i'm confused. Is a sparse graph effectively a big one, with millions/billions of nodes. An example, is a real world one - like Facebook. Or can they be in small networks as well?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Practically speaking, a graph is spare when O(E) is closer to O(V) then O(V^2). Where E is the number of edges and V is the number of vertices.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, it is said that a graph with *n* vertices is *dense* if it has Theta(*n*^2) edges and is *sparse* otherwise. This means that a graph is dense if the average degree of each vertex is lineal, and sparse if sublineal.

Sparsity does not deppend on size. For instance, trees are sparse (because a tree with *n* nodes has *n-1* edges).

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_graph#Sparse_and_tight_graphs). I guess you can say that a graph can be considered sparse if each vertice is part of few edges in comparison to how many it would be part of if the graph were complete.

So basically, graphs do not HAVE to be huge to be sparse. Any tree can be considered a sparse graph, for instance, regardless of the number of nodes.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Beware: any tree is sparse, but the given reason (each node won't have more than 2 edges) is not correct. An n-node star is a tree and there is a node with n-1 edges. In a binary tree, most nodes have 3 edges...

Comment: That's absolutely right! Thanks for pointing that out; I don't know what I was thinking when writing this example :)